# mssql select with union subquery join and like is very slow

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery, left-join, union

```
SELECT 
TOP 10 pcchrgcod
FROM ( 
SELECT TOP 10 acctno AS pcchrgcod FROM hdocord
WHERE acctno LIKE '2007-000%' 
GROUP BY 
acctno
UNION

SELECT TOP 10 acctno AS pcchrgcod FROM hpatchrg
WHERE acctno LIKE '2007-000%' 
GROUP BY 
acctno 
UNION

SELECT TOP 10 acctno AS pcchrgcod FROM hrqd
WHERE acctno LIKE '2007-000%' 
GROUP BY 
acctno
UNION

SELECT TOP 10 acctno AS pcchrgcod FROM hrxo
WHERE acctno LIKE '2007-000%'   
GROUP BY 
acctno 
)
sub 
GROUP BY 
pcchrgcod
```

This is my select with union and subquery and like and this is returning ok result but it is very slow. So I change union into JOIN and I got this

```
SELECT TOP 10  coalesce(t1.acctno, MAX(t2.acctno),MAX(t3.acctno),MAX(t4.acctno)) AS pcchrgcod 
--t1.acctno AS t1pcchrgcod,
--t2.acctno AS t2pcchrgcod,
--t3.acctno AS t3pcchrgcod,
--t4.acctno AS t4pcchrgcod
FROM hdocord    AS t1 LEFT JOIN 
hpatchrg AS t2 ON t1.acctno = t2.acctno LEFT JOIN 
hrqd AS t3 ON t2.acctno = t3.acctno LEFT JOIN 
hrxo AS t4 ON t3.acctno = t4.acctno 
WHERE t1.acctno LIKE '2007-000%'    
GROUP BY 
t1.acctno
--t2.acctno,
--t3.acctno,
--t4.acctno
```

Still it is very slow.

How can I make this select run faster?

`UPDATE`

[image]

`UPDATE`

[estiamte plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyXaw8OPZ)

[actual plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkLUSUOP-)

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan, https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: Are you worried about duplicates? If not, try using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, since `UNION` is actually making sure to return distinct values.

Comment: No it is just very slow when i run it in sql server management it takes around 35 - 40 to return result of 10 records and it is very slow

Comment: Anyway, this is just an attempt..for the solution you should check out the execution plan and maybe post it [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for SO contributors to see and try to help you.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri should i add here what i get in the execution plan?

Comment: @Martin, just update your question with the execution plan.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri added the plan the first isnt included it wont fit

Comment: DDL? Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on your usage, which you did not specify, please update your question.

You can either use materialized views alias `index views` in MS SQL or you can create a temporary table which will contain all the information you need and you can take the information from there.

The main reason why it is so slow is the usage of `LIKE`.  You should come up with a way (via execution plan) which would remove it.